# PLIST UPDATING CHANGING THE KEY FROM ITEM O TO SOME NAME 

Tags: iphone

every one

i have a problem with my plist ,i was able to write the data to plist which is type Dictionary ,and consists of 4 string items , and my problem is i want to change the dictionary key value to some example: 500k but it is showing default item 0, i want to change this to 500k

below is the code i implemented.

```
NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


[nameDictionary setValue:Name  forKey:@"fullName"];
[nameDictionary setValue:Salary  forKey:@"salary"];
[nameDictionary setValue:Experience forKey:@"expreience"];
[nameDictionary setValue:Designation forKey:@"designation"];



NSMutableArray *plist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/nikhil/Desktop/secondProgram/secondProgram/new2.plist"];
NSLog(@"wat is in plist %d",[plist count]);

if (plist == nil)
plist = [NSMutableArray array];


[plist addObject:nameDictionary];
[plist writeToFile:@"/Users/nikhil/Desktop/secondProgram/secondProgram/new2.plist" atomically:YES];
```

and in plist is show ing

> item 0  | Dictionary | (4items)

i want to change it to

> 500K    | Dictionary | (4items)

Please help me ....

Comment: Please supply more information.

Comment: in which method u want index. put some code

Comment: What's the situation in which you are in need of the cell index? You've got a reference to a cell and want to find out which index its at?

Comment: indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath: will certainly give you the index path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below function of UITableView will  return an index path representing the row and section of a given table-view cell.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
```

Read Apple Doc for `UITableView`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html